# Are two calls to cout less efficient than one?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, cout

I have two questions:

1. Is two calls to std::cout less efficient than one?
2. If yes, does the compiler (usually) optimize it and generate equal assembly for the three cases shown below?

For example:

```
std::cout << "a" << "b";
```

or

```
std::cout << "ab";
```

or

```
std::cout << "a";
std::cout << "b";
```

I ask, because I think the last one is the most readable for a longer list of text to output.

Comment: `cout` performance is dominated by I/O. Don't micro-optimise things that don't matter. Keep your code clear.

Comment: You've also chosen a contrived case.  No one would write the code you have here.  If the strings were variables then you would have to concatenate them, which would surely cost more than a function call.  Of course, you'd have no other option anyway.

Comment: @EJP: My question might be more theoretical than practical.

Comment: You could run both versions in a loop and time it if that kind of thing really matters to you.

Comment: @Phataas Irrelevant. The answer is the same. The rate-determining step is the I/O, either theoretically or practically.

Comment: The overhead of `cout<<` compared to a simple `puts` is way more than just a function call and may not always be negligible compared to buffered I/O. However, if you are calling `cout<<`, this must not be a time-critical part of your program, so you don't need to optimize it for speed.

Comment: NB If you're asking whether concatenating strings outside or, effectively, inside a function is faster, without regard to the I/O which is what this function actually does, the answer is obviously 'no', more or less. If you're asking whether concatenating strings at compile time is more efficient than doing so at runtime,, the answer is obviously 'yes'. But you didn't ask those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In THIS example,

```
std::cout << "ab";
```

is more efficient (and I have not seen a compiler "merge" the output, but I must say I haven't been looking for that either - I'll go look and edit if I find something interesting).

Edit: Clang (version 3.7 as of last weekend) does not merge the string in the case of:

```
std::cout << "a" << "b";
```

The other two code snippets are identical except for number of lines and source code size [which generally has no impact on the executable, so "doesn't matter"].

As mentioned in the comments, if you actually have two strings that are for example variables, the overhead of constructing a new string is almost certainly not worth the trouble, and very rarely does the performance of `std::cout` matter at all to the overall performance of the application, other than the overall I/O bandwidth limiting the execution of the application. In other words, trying to save a few microseconds when it takes several milliseconds to write something to a console is pointless.